# Adding additional information to form fields with dropzone-rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I have a form that takes in a name, description, subject and a file upload with dropzone. I've managed to get dropzone to work were you hit the submit button , and it processes the uploaded file and uploads. The problem is dropzone only uploads the file attachment, but the rest of the form is discluded, and results in all null values for the model. Does anyone know how i can get dropzone to process my entire form and not just the stuff in the dropbox area.

This is the form

```
<div class="container">


  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 25px;">

    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
      <button style="font-size:22px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary upload-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click Here To Upload!  <i class="fa fa-video-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button><br>

      <div class="well">
        <h4 class = "text-center"><b>All Of Your Current Posts </b></h4><%= form_tag '/pins/new', method: :delete do %>
            <%= submit_tag 'Delete Selected Item', id: 'delete', class: 'btn btn-danger warn', disabled: @media_contents.empty? %>              <%= link_to 'Delete All', delete_all_path, method: :delete, id: 'delete-all', class: 'btn btn-danger', disabled: @media_contents.empty? %>
            <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-10">
<br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div id="media-contents" class="col-lg-12">
                    <% if @media_contents.empty? %>
                        <h5 id="no-media">No Media Found</h5>
                    <% else %>
                        <% @media_contents.each do |media| %>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                              <div class="thumbnail">
                                <% if media.file_name.file.extension == "mp4" %>
                                    <video style = "width: 100%; height: auto; " id="my-video" class="video-js pin_image" controls autoplay preload="auto"
                                           poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
                                      <source src="<%= media.file_name.url %>" type='video/mp4'>
                                      <source src="<%= media.file_name.url %>" type='video/webm'>
                                      <source src="<%= media.file_name.url %>" type='video/ogg'>
                                      <p class="vjs-no-js">
                                        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
                                        <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                                      </p>
                                    </video>

                                <% elsif media.file_name.file.extension == "pdf" %>
                                    <iframe src="<%= media.file_name.url %>"  frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" style="  border:1px solid #CCC; border-width:1px; height:auto; width: 100%;" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
                                <% else %>

                                    <%= image_tag media.file_name.url %>

                                <% end %>
                                <div class="caption">
                                  <p>
                                    <%= check_box_tag 'media_contents[]', media.id %>
                                  </p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>
            <div class="col-md-1">
            </div>
          </div>




    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title " id="myModalLabel">Upload New</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= simple_form_for @media, html: { multipart: true, class: 'dropzone form', id: 'mydropzone' } do |f| %>
            <% if @media.errors.any? %>
                <div id="errors">
                  <h2>
                    <%= pluralize(@media.errors.count, "error") %>
                    prevented this Pin from saving
                  </h2>
                  <ul>
                    <% @media.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                        <li>
                          <%= msg %>
                        </li>
                    <% end %>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            <% end %>

            <div class = "controls">
              <%= f.select(:subject, options_for_select([['', ''],['Math', 'Math'], ['English', 'English'], ['Science', 'Science'], ['History', 'History'], ['Geography', 'Geography'], ['Physics', 'Physics'], ['Chemistry', 'Chemistry'], ['Biology', 'Biology'], ['Algebra', 'Algebra'], ['Social Studies', 'Social Studies'], ['Art', 'Art'], ['Physical Education', 'Physical Education'], ['Economics', 'Economics'], ['Writing', 'Writing'], ['Astronomy', 'Astronomy'], ['Mechanics', 'Mechanics'], ['Language', 'Language'], ['ICT', 'ICT'], ['Religious Education', 'Religious Education'], ['Logic', 'Logic'], ['Music', 'Music'], ['Psychology', 'Psychology'], ['Sexual Education', 'Sexual Education'], ['Computer Science', 'Computer Science'], ['General Business', 'General Business'], ['Ethics', 'Ethics'], ['Foreign Languages', 'Foreign Languages'], ['Computers', 'Computers'], ['Greek', 'Greek'], ['Reading', 'Reading'], ['Life Skills', 'Life Skills'], ['Drama', 'Drama'], ['Handwriting', 'Handwriting'], ['Food Tech', 'Food Tech'], ['Cooking Class', 'Cooking Class'], ['Gym', 'Gym'], ['Drivers Education', 'Drivers Education'], ['German', 'German'], ['Urdu', 'Urdu'], ['Human Relations', 'Human Relations'], ['Design And Technology', 'Design And Technology'], ['French', 'French'], ['Values Education', 'Values Education'], ['Accounting', 'Accounting'], ['Philosophy', 'Philosophy'], ['Home Economics', 'Home Economics'],  ['Health', 'Health'], ['Media Studies', 'Media Studies']])) %>
            </div>
            <div class="fallback">
              <%= f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
            </div>
            <div class="fallback">
              <%= f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
            </div>

            <div class="fallback">
              <%= file_field_tag 'media', multiple: true %>
            </div>

            <%= f.button :submit , "Post!",  class: "btn btn-primary", id: "submitbtn" %>


        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the javascript

```
Dropzone.options.mydropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

    // The configuration we've talked about above
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    autoDiscover: false,

    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 3,
    accept: function(file, done) {
        console.log("uploaded");
        done();
    },
    error: function(file, msg){
        alert(msg);
    },
    init: function() {

        var myDropzone = this;
        //now we will submit the form when the button is clicked
        $("#submitbtn").on('click',function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
            // this will submit your form to the specified action path
            // after this, your whole form will get submitted with all the inputs + your files and the php code will remain as usual
            //REMEMBER you DON'T have to call ajax or anything by yourself, dropzone will take care of that
        });

    } // init end

};
```

And this is my create action

```
def create
    @media = Pin.new(user_id: current_user.id, file_name: params[:file], )
    if @media.save
      render json: { message: "success", fileID: @media.id }, :status => 200
    else
      render json: { error: @media.errors.full_messages.join(',')}, :status => 400
    end
    end
  end
```